# Unexpected results of EventTrigger in loop

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, eventtrigger

I populated a grid layout with an array of GameObjects (image sprites) in a loop. Inside the loop I want the images to be clickable and take the players to different scenes.

If a try the following it works:

```
    EventTrigger[] trigger = new EventTrigger[pocet];
    EventTrigger.Entry[] entries = new EventTrigger.Entry[pocet];

    entries[0] = new EventTrigger.Entry();
    entries[0].eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerUp;
    entries[0].callback.AddListener((eventData) => {
    newObj[0].transform.localScale += new Vector3(2f, 2f, 0);
       });
    trigger[0].triggers.Add(entries[0]);
```

I can keep copying it with all the indexes and it would work properly, however
if I create it in a loop like this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i<pocet-1;i++)
        {
        entries[i] = new EventTrigger.Entry();
        entries[i].eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerUp;
        entries[i].callback.AddListener((eventData) => {
            newObj[i].transform.localScale += new Vector3(2f, 2f, 0);
        });
        trigger[i].triggers.Add(entries[i]);
        }
```

The EventTrigger works on all of the images but always the last image (object) gets scaled up. Almost like the Listeners are reset and only the last one is remembered, I dont know what to change in order to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the iterator `i` in the lambda expression.

When it finally comes to the call the last value is used for `i` in all of the buttons.

→ store it in a variable first

```
var index = i; 
entries[i].callback.AddListener((eventData) => {
    newObj[index].transform.localScale += new Vector3(2f, 2f, 0);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that is indeed what the problem was. Thank you for your help. Have a nice day!